# django - search function with relational query

Tags: django

I am attempting to create a search functionality that returns products that are associated with a vendor. In each listing that is returned I would like to have the vendor name and create a link to the vendor's page using the vendor primary key.

The relationship between both tables is created in a `vendor_id` as a foreign key pointing to the vendor table.

Ideally in the output I could do something like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.title}} <br />
    {{product.description}} <br />
    <a href="{% url 'vendor' vendor.id %}">{{vendor.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I can get all vendors, but that seems inefficient, and I am not sure how to make the relationship between the vendor who "owns" the product in that cycle of the loop. I've seen a post on `select_related` but that did not work for me, and appears to be used with `objects.get` instead of `objects.filter`

Here is my search functionality defined in view.py

```
def search(request):
    queryset_list = Products.objects.order_by('id')

    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']

        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

    context = {
        'products': queryset_list
    }

    return render(request, 'products/search.html', context)
```

models (products)

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendors, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

models (vendor)

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    uid = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: can you paste your models Product and Owner?

Comment: @NakulNarayanan added, I haven't given them much detail yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the vender of the corresponding product by **`product.vendor.id`** in the template
try this,

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.title}} <br />
    {{product.description}} <br />
    <a href="{% url 'vendor' product.vendor.id %}">{{product.vendor.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.title}} <br />
    {{product.description}} <br />
    <a href="{% url 'vendor' product.vendor.id %}">{{product.vendor.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excellent, this did work, however I don't understand how. Could you explain it?

Comment: please go through this doc!  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey when you try to access the field `product.vendor` django orm  will perform a join operation with vendor table and return the instance of vendor_id